# What can we get from (Brauer) character tables of a finite group?

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory

I want to know what can we get from (Brauer) character tables of a finite group. such as block distribution, the liftablity of a character and so on. For example, we can get both character table and Brauer character of $A_5$ from 'Atlas of fintie groups' and 'An atlas of Brauer charcters' respectively. How can I know the information of the blocks of $A_5$ or any properties of the characters of $A_5$?

Answer (score 0):

There is now a paper by Navarro with the title "What do the modular characters know?" ([published](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs13398-019-00733-1)). He asked if the $p$-Brauer character table of a finite group $G$ determines the $p'$-part $|G|_{p'}$ (it is impossible to determine $|G|$). This has been answered affirmatively by Sambale ([arxiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.06150), [published](http://publi.math.unideb.hu/load_jpg.php?p=2477)). Navarro proved that the Brauer character table determines if $G$ is solvable. In general, it seems there is not much information to get from the Brauer character table.